# Hiding element affects other unrelated element when using Bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dashboard and in the top navigation i display the date and time in two separate divs as seen below. The div tags are self explanatory. I'm using bootstrap with my site to keep the rows and columns tidy.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="Date"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <ul class="time">
                        <li id="hours"></li>
                        <li id="point">:</li>
                        <li id="min"></li>
                        <li id="point">:</li>
                        <li id="sec"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

My Issue is that i have a settings panel where you can toggle the date or the time. The toggle works fine however when you toggle the the date the time looses its style and the list goes vertical. Any ideas how i can stop this. I have included a fiddle so you can see the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1t9d6Ly/).
Thank you for any help. In my head i can see it as a styling issue possibly due to bootstrap but i cant figure it out.

Before the toggle the time id displayed like this: 
[image: Time before date is toggled]
And after the date is toggled time displays like this:
[image: After the date is toggled]

Comment: working fine in chrome

Comment: the toggle is not the issue, its the style of the time, after you click it changes from horizontal alignment to vertical. I'm trying to keep it horizontal if that makes sense.

Comment: @Tony_89 I see no difference in the styling of the time after toggling.

Comment: I've updated the issue with screenshots to show how it looks for me when i toggle the date.

Comment: what browser are you using

Comment: I am using chrome but i have also checked in IE and Firefox and i am getting the same result. I think its because i am using nested columns, when i hide the date it seems to be affecting the time also. however if i don't use nested columns, if i remove the col-xs-12 then i don't get this issue.

Comment: To all of the people attempting to replicate the behavior: You won't see the problem unless you make the rendered frame big wide enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you're trying to use fluid layout in a container that doesn't have set width. This means that the content will only stretch to contain the widest line of flow content. When you display the date, it makes your container larger, and that in turn will give more space to the time column. When you hide the date, the container only stretches to accomodate the widest item, which is one of the numbers.

**Set a width on your container** (`.clock`) **before trying to use fluid layout.**

Comment: That did the trick thank you, i thought it was something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for hon2a for finding out the issue what was affecting the layout of the time value. Following hon2a's answer I also tried to set a class value `container` for the `div` that has `class = "clock"`. So I changed:

```
 <div class="clock">
```

to

```
 <div class="container">
```

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) documentation says: *"Rows must be placed within a **.container** (fixed-width) or **.container-fluid** (full-width) for proper alignment and padding."* This worked too when I tested it with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/y1t9d6Ly/9/).